# haproxy: command not found

Tags: linux, apt, haproxy

I am trying to use haproxy on linux. I installed it using `sudo apt install haproxy` but after install is complete when I run `haproxy -vv` i get error `haproxy: command not found`. I tried running `sudo systemctl status haproxy.service -l --no-pager` and it shows that haproxy load balancer is active(running). What is happening? Why isn't haproxy command not found? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think such command should be? Its just your wish?

Comment: Try 'sudo haproxy', 'type haproxy', 'find / -iname haproxy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the executable is installed in a directory that isn't in your `$PATH`. You can run `dpkg -L haproxy` to see exactly where things were installed. On an Ubuntu 20.04 system, if I `apt install haproxy`, I see:

```
$ dpkg -L haproxy | grep bin/
/usr/bin/halog
/usr/sbin/haproxy
```

So we can see that the executable is in `/usr/sbin/haproxy`.

Often, `/usr/sbin` isn't in the `$PATH` of non-root users. You can add it to your `$PATH`, or just use the fully qualified path (`/usr/sbin/haproxy`).

Comment: can you please take a look at this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717030/failed-to-start-haproxy-load-balancer